# Scripting Animation blocks iOS

Tags: ios, animation, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to animate a series of full screen images. Each image will be animated in a different way. I'd like to store these animations somewhere either in a database or plist or whatever, I just don't want to have them hard coded.  The animations will be very simple, objects within the image will jiggle or bounce or what have you. I'm going to animate the objects using blocks and ideally i'd like the individual blocks to be stored in the data store. I'd like to avoid using a separate scripting language or something like that.

What is my best course of action?

Comment: What goal(s) are you trying to achieve by storing the blocks in a data store?

Comment: There are going to be about 75+ images that are animated. I think it would be easier to script that than hard code it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store them in, for example, a plist, you can do something like this:

```
<plist>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>filename</key>
        <string>first.jpg</string>
        <key>animation</key>
        <string>bounce</string>
        <key>duration</key>
        <real>0.5</real>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>filename</key>
        <string>second.jpg</string>
        <key>animation</key>
        <string>easeinout</string>
        <key>duration</key>
        <real>1.0</real>
    </dict>
    <!-- et cetera -->
</array>
</plist>
```

Then you can decode this into actual animations by writing something like the following code snippet:

```
- (void)loadAnimations
{
    NSArray *animations = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/H2CO3/animations.plist"];
    for (NSDictionary *animation in animations)
    {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[animation objectForKey:@"filename"]];
        NSString *animationType = [animation objectForKey:@"animation"];
        float duration = [(NSNumber *)[animation objectForKey:@"duration"] floatValue];

        if ([animationType isEqualToString:@"bounce"])
        {
            /* animation block 1 */
        }
        else if ([animationType isEqualToString:@"easeinout"])
        {
            /* animation block 2 */
        }
        /* Et cetera... */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was thinking of taking this approach. It may be the easiest option.

Comment: The approach above of calling imageNamed will crash on your device because it will consume all available memory once you have more than 1 or 2 images. A better approach is to use a timer and then load 1 specific frame (PNG image) each time the timer is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what benefit you might get from storing the animations in a data store, if that were possible. If you just don't want to repeat the animation code, you can put it in a method and pass the view(s) to the method.

```
-(void)jiggle:(UIView *)image {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.1
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
                     animations:^{
                         image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-5 * M_PI / 180);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:.1
                                               delay:0
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
                                          animations:^{
                                              image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(5 * M_PI / 180);
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                              [UIView animateWithDuration:.1
                                                                    delay:0
                                                                  options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
                                                               animations:^{
                                                                   image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0 * M_PI / 180);
                                                               }
                                                               completion:nil
                                               ];
                                          }
                          ];
                     }
     ];
}
```

Comment: For 75 images, indent will freak out seeing this.

Comment: And, btw, this does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: @H2CO3, the indentation is for a series of steps in the animation--it has nothing to do with the number of files, as this is an animation that could be applied to any view. There are ways to define this kind of animation without nested completion blocks, and your solution would require doing something like this as well. I was trying to help OP resolve his problem, not answer the question as posted, because I don't see how a data store helps him.