# how to create an iphone app which generates animations based on input xml

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, ipad, core-animation

I have to create an iphone app which takes inputs from an xml and generates animations according to that, similar to a swf and its swf tags,

for example, i would say an image at certain position and certain size stays on the stage for 3 seconds...

Basically i need a player which plays all my swf files whose xml representation i can generate...

I would like to know how to go about doing the same, or if anyone has previous experience about this, any help would be appreciated

Thanks :)

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491451/scripting-animation-blocks-ios

Comment: @h2co3 thanks for looking into this question, and this is not exactly what im looking for, i have say a set of questions, each question can be considered as a slide, and when you answer one, the next one is shown, and i have xml info of all these questions :)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to play swf files you might want to look into the Adobe Air product. That would give you full flash support in your apps, at the cost of including the Flash player in your app.

If you want to create Core Animation animations on the fly from data in an XML file, you've got your work cut out for you. It should be possible, but it would be a fairly complex thing to design and implement. How you go about it would depend on your specific requirements.